# Battery charging 1.2 Testing (BC 1.2)

Tags: usb, battery-charging

USB IF has specified tests for devices with BC1.2 Ability.
I am checking their original literature on the matter but it's just too complicated for my understanding. is there any link on these tests or example somewhere that someone can help with?

Comment: BC1.2 is dead. Don't waste your time on this outdated and never used technology.

Comment: Why ? What's it replaced with

Comment: It is replaced with (a) Type-C CC pull-up-down mechanism, and (b) with Power Delivery at a higher level.